# Converting hexadecimal string to char

Tags: c, arduino, hex

I got "3838" as String. Like :

```
String example = "3838";
```

Which is equal to ( 88 ) as a hexadecimal. ( I converted here : http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/ )

But I need to use it as a char like here :

```
char data[] = {0x88,0x0f,0xc7,0xae,0x76,0x85,0xe9,0xb1,0x8f,0x2f,0x2a,0xd3,0x60,0x37,0x6b,0x6d};
```

How can I do this ? Sorry for bad expression. Thank you very much.

Comment: How can `3838` in decimal be `88` in hex?

Comment: 0x38 is character '8' in ascii-table. No idea if that is what OP is asking...

Comment: @StephanLechner I think he's saying 0x38 is the ASCII code for '8', so "3838" is "88"

Comment: Are you trying to convert each character to a hex value or the whole string into one hex value? Or each two characters? It isnt very clear.

Comment: Please explain the relation between the string which looks like a number and the content of the the array. If the array is representing a string, explain and maybe show the content of the string. wouldn't  you like a ' \0' at the end?

Comment: Also, technically, this is C++ as [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) is an Arduino specific class.

Comment: Hello everyone, I actually have the decimal number "14392" which gave me "3838" as hexadecimal value. It also works if I can convert 14392 decimal to 0x88 char. Thanks everyone. And yes, I'm working with Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments it seems as if you want to interpret the higher and the lower byte of a 16 bit integral value (e.g. `14392`) as ASCII-characters (e.g. `'8'`+`'8'`). To achieve that, you do not have to "convert" the decimal value into a hex value in order to then get an ASCII-character. You could simply *interpret* the higher and the lower byte as an (ASCII-) char; Then - if needed - you can interpret two consecutive ASCII-characters as a string representing a hex-value and convert it to decimal. 
No idea why you actually need that, but see the following code that does exactly that. Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    u_int16_t decVal = 14392;
    cout << "original dec value: " << decVal << endl;
    cout << "dec value as hex: 0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << decVal  << endl;
    char c1 = (decVal&0x7F00 >> 8);
    char c2 = (decVal&0x7F);
    char hexStr[3] = { c1, c2, '\0' };
    cout << "2 bytes interpreted as ASCII: " << hexStr << endl;

    char *lastCharInterpreted;
    decVal = strtol(hexStr, &lastCharInterpreted, 16);
    if (lastCharInterpreted == hexStr) {
        cout << "invalid hexadecimal value: "  << hexStr << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "ASCII interpreted as hex and converted to dec:" << std::dec << decVal << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
original dec value: 14392
dec value as hex: 0x3838
2 bytes interpreted as ASCII: 88
ASCII interpreted as hex and converted to dec:136
```

Comment: I think we have "3838" as a string, and therefore 4 bytes (not two). Thats the input.

now we want to get the numerical value of each 2 bytes as hexa (0x38 is the char '8'). Take the hexa chars and make them hexa numbers again, i.e. getting 0x88, which in decimal will be 136 (10001000).

Comment: @N O, that is exactly what I need. I need decimal 136.

Comment: @Stephan Lechner thank you very much. But it didn't actually solve my problems. Is it possible to do what N O said ?

Comment: @Atalay K.: getting from `14392` to `136` is really confusing :-) hope the code helps.

Comment: @Stephan Lechner you are amazing ! :) Thank you very very much. I implement the code to Arduino without any problem. There is just one problem. This code can't handle decimal 13872 (It's actually 3630 hexadecimal ) value. c1 and c2 values are 0. What can be the problem is ?

Comment: also 25648 , 12592 to give you some examples.

Comment: try instead  (decVal & 0x7F00 )>> 8

Comment: @datafiddler ahh thank you. It solved it. But I actually don't know what I'm doing with >>8 and 0x7F00. How can I learn it ? I mean what does it called in literature ?

Comment: That's plain C. ( according to the tag, you guessed that already ;) It's splitting an int16 into 2 bytes. You should learn a few basics. And probably you're doing nonsense somewhere else, to end up in this task...

Comment: @datafiddler I'm taking the data from a i2c register. It gives me 2 char in 1 decimal. And I'm not expert of these topics. I mostly work with web based applications. It solved my problem without any speed issue.

Comment: @datafiddler It's keeping to give me c1 and c2 which are 0. Do you have any other idea to solve this problem ?